# Looking for common solution to validate Excel reports (ETL)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm trying to more efficiently validate financial reports generated in Excel.

Currently, a user generates around 300 reports in Excel using different Sheets in each. These reports use extensive features of Excel and populate the data in pre-formatted sheets. The users must validate particular cell values between sheets to ensure accuracy e.g. in Sheet1 Total Values should match with Sheet2 Total Values.

I have automated this somewhere by creating Macro Modules in one Excel file to validate the values among the sheets, but my issue is as the number of  reports continue to increase I have to copy this code to each new and run it.

How can I make these macros available all the time in my Excel so that I can run them on whatever report I happen to have open at the time?

Comment: look into how to save the module into a personal.xslm file. This should make the macro always available and across workbooks. You may have to update references in the macro to be more generic...